# How to get image from json response?

Tags: android, json

Hello I am trying to get data using JSON in my application activity from response i get all data perfectly except image,its not showing in my output..i don't know what is problem using simple `setTag` and `setText` method with it, can any one help?

```
public class ProfilePage extends Activity{

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//private static final String TAG_MATCH_ID="match_detail_id";

private static final String USER_NAME="name";
private static final String USER_AGE="age";
private static final String USER_LOCATION="location";
private static final String USER_MOTHER_TONGE="mother_tounge";
private static final String USER_OCCU="occupation";
private static final String USER_INCOM="income";
private static final String USER_HEIGHT="height";
private static final String USER_MARRAGE="marital_status";
private static final String USER_RELIGION="religion";
private static final String USER_GOTRA="gotra";
private static final String USER_MANGLIK="manglik";
private static final String USER_RASHI="rashi";
private static final String USER_EDUCATION="education";
private static final String USER_EAT="eating";
private static final String USER_DRINK="drink";
private static final String USER_SMOKE="smoke";
private static final String USER_ABOUT="about_me";
private static final String USER_PIC="profile_pic";

private static String USER_URL="http://abcfg.com/webservice/matchingdetails?version=apps&match_detail_id=636";

String user_match_id;

private ImageView cover;
private ImageView yes;
private ImageView no;
private ImageView sendmsg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_page);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
     ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(USER_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            String user_name = jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME);
            String user_age = jsonObj.getString(USER_AGE);
            String user_location = jsonObj.getString(USER_LOCATION);
            String user_mothertong = jsonObj.getString(USER_MOTHER_TONGE);
            String user_occupation = jsonObj.getString(USER_OCCU);
            String user_income = jsonObj.getString(USER_INCOM);
            String user_height = jsonObj.getString(USER_HEIGHT);
            String user_marg = jsonObj.getString(USER_MARRAGE);
            String user_religion = jsonObj.getString(USER_RELIGION);
            String user_gotra = jsonObj.getString(USER_GOTRA);
            String user_manglik = jsonObj.getString(USER_MANGLIK);
            String user_rashi = jsonObj.getString(USER_RASHI);
            String user_education = jsonObj.getString(USER_EDUCATION);
            String user_eat = jsonObj.getString(USER_EAT);
            String user_drink = jsonObj.getString(USER_DRINK);
            String user_smoke = jsonObj.getString(USER_SMOKE);
            String user_about = jsonObj.getString(USER_ABOUT);
           String user_pro = jsonObj.getString(USER_PIC);

            final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namedetail);
           final TextView fdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstdetail);
            final TextView sdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seconddetail);
            final TextView tdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirddetail);
            final TextView ocdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtoccupationdetail);
            final TextView incomedetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incomedetaile);
            final TextView uheight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtheightprofile);
            final TextView umrg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmrgprofile);
            final TextView ureligion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prohindu);
            final TextView ugotra = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gothraa);
            final TextView umanglik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usermanglik);
            final TextView urashi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rashi);
            final TextView udegree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userdegree);
            final TextView ueat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txteatprofile);
            final TextView udrink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdrinkprofile);
            final TextView usmoke = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtsmokeprofile);
            final TextView uabout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtabouther);
           final ImageView ucover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.coverimage);

            uname.setText(user_name);
            fdetail.setText(user_age+" years");
            sdetail.setText(user_location);
            tdetail.setText(user_mothertong);
            ocdetail.setText(user_occupation);
            incomedetail.setText(user_income);
            uheight.setText(user_height);
            umrg.setText(user_marg);
            ureligion.setText(user_religion);
            ugotra.setText(user_gotra);
            umanglik.setText(user_manglik);
            urashi.setText(user_rashi);
            udegree.setText(user_education);
            ueat.setText(user_eat);
            udrink.setText(user_drink);
            usmoke.setText(user_smoke);
            uabout.setText(user_about);
            ucover.setTag(user_pro);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where you displaying your Image, here I can not see any code.

Comment: last field is image see in my code

Comment: ucover.setTag(user_pro); is this code for display Image?

Comment: yes i am this code but image is not displaying

Comment: What is the image format returned from Json ? is it a path to an image or some image byte data ?

Comment: @Eddie It will not show your Image, see my answer below I am posting.

Comment: @pratt ok post your anser

Comment: @sharath image is not displaying

Comment: @Eddie you have to set the image to the imageview and not settag it. Also if you want the displaying image process to be faster and much simpler , you better use Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @Eddie see my answer below.

Comment: @Eddie,setTag() is not use for showing image which used for keep some data with View.

Comment: @HareshChhelana then which method will i use

Comment: @Eddie,you wan to show image from url or local ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana no check my response url in my question

Comment: @Eddie,I think you have already now how to load image using AndroidQuery please use AndroidQuery to load image as you already doing in list adapter.

Comment: but here i am not using listview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65119/discussion-between-haresh-chhelana-and-eddie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are downloading Image from url, so I am suggesting you to use Android Query for this, you will never get this error if you used it.

You can download the jar file from here : [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list) Download the jar file and set jar to your Build Path.

```
 AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example to load image directly from url:

```
androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true);
```

As an example to get Bitmap from url:

```
androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

                    });
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading; getting a bitmap, if needed; etc.

Comment: so may jar files there which i should download

Comment: @Eddie first one from the list, top of the list.

Comment: ok but its showing error for AjaxStatus and asking to create class AjaxStatus cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Eddie dont use that code, just use this single line : androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true); that;s it

Comment: check out this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971326/how-to-pass-id-of-one-json-to-next-activity

Comment: @Eddie Check that link, I have posted reply there.

Comment: which link you talking about?

Comment: @Eddie Which you were given to me for check

Answer (score 0):

> use ION library.... its very simple to fetch image from network.... like this,

```
Ion.with(context).load("url").withBitmap()
            .resize(512, 512).centerCrop().intoImageView(image);
```

> try this....

Comment: you have to first add library ION and GSON and then simply add this code into your MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Here is the feasible solution:
First get the URL of image from JSON using this-

```
String imgURL = json.getString(JSON_TAG_OF_IMAGE);  //Getting the URL
```

Now, get the image from URL using following code, (surround with try/catch)

```
try {

    getBitmapFromUrl(imgURL);    //getBitmapFromUrl is a methos by which image is downloaded
    photo = bmp;                 //photo is Bitmap varible and bmp is bitmap returned by getBitmapFromUrl 

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d(_TAG, "Bitmap Not Received");
}
```

Here is the getBitmapFromurl:--

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String hos_imgURL)
            throws IOException {

        URL IMGURL = new URL(hos_imgURL);
        Log.d(_TAG, "Image Url:" + IMGURL.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) IMGURL.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        return bmp;
    }
```

That's it. You can set bitmap(photo variable) to imageview.
Hope this helps :) :)